# Acceleration needed to make a solid turn into gas?

Tags: energy, acceleration, gas

There's a joke in a show in France where it is said speaking of a human that he would turn into gas if accelerated enough.

My questions :

- Is this possible without friction ?
- What would be this acceleration with atmospheric friction ? And, if possible, without friction ?

Comment: Uh...whatever you're doing, I think that "human" stops being an adequate label for the result long before its turned into gas.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about physics.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Ok, human is for the joke... Let's talk about a random solid if you prefer. I'm interested about a vague idea of this acceleration, not a biologically true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To turn a solid into a gas you would have to heat it. I can't think of any way in which acceleration would cause heating, so acceleration won't turn you or any other solid into a gas.

The side effects of acceleration could do this. For example if I dropped you onto a neutron star then your velocity when you hit the surface would be a significant percentage of the speed of light. The resulting impact would most effectively turn you into a gas if not a plasma. However the cause is your kinetic energy that is converted to heat, not any direct effect of acceleration.